# Using Reflection get value of the field on c#

Tags: c#

I want to get value of the `subfield('m_fullDescriptor')` however it throws an error like below. How can i get the value of the subfield?

Structure;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KneIE.png)
[image]
Code;

```
 public class FieldsClass
        {
            public string fieldA;

            public FieldsClass()
            {
                fieldA = "A public field";
            }
        }


FieldsClass fieldsInst = new FieldsClass();

var specFields = con.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).Single(pi => pi.Name == "pmCS").FieldType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).Single(pi => pi.Name == "m_pm").FieldType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).Single(pi => pi.Name == "m_fullDescriptor");

fieldsInst.fieldA= (string)specFields.GetValue(con);
```

I get below Error;

```
System.ArgumentException: 'Field 'm_fullDescriptor' defined on type 'OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager`3[OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OraclePoolManager,OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OraclePool,OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleConnectionImpl]' is not a field on the target object which is of type 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection'.'
```

Comment: Do you understand the error message? You are looking for a field on the wrong Type. It might be easier to reason about the code if you didn't have so many calls chained together on one line.

Comment: as you can see on the image, field is the child of the field is that chield of another field. How can i call it simpler? The field type is string. Do you see anything different?

Comment: Break it into multiple lines so you can at least debug it

Comment: i already debugged, no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `Single` from Linq to find the field you need. Use `GetField` method, it already takes exact name of the field. Flags can be reused as well.

To get value, an object is needed to be passed where that field is defined.

I believe this should work, not tested.

```
var flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;

var pmCS = connection.GetType().GetField("pmCS", flags).GetValue(connection);
var m_pm = pmCS.GetType().GetField("m_pm", flags).GetValue(pmCS);
var m_fullDescriptor = m_pm.GetType().GetField("m_fullDescriptor", flags).GetValue(m_pm);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the value of the `m_fullDescriptor` which exists on the `OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OraclePoolManager` type, but you are passing an object (`con`) to  `GetValue` that is not of that type.

Something like this should work, however, I was unable to test it because I do not have access to an Oracle Database.

```
var pmCSField = connection.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).Single(pi => pi.Name == "pmCS");

var m_pmField = pmCSField.FieldType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).Single(pi => pi.Name == "m_pm");

var m_fullDescriptorField = m_pmField.FieldType.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).Single(pi => pi.Name == "m_fullDescriptor");

var pmCSFieldValue = pmCSField.GetValue(connection);

var m_pmFieldValue = m_pmField.GetValue(pmCSFieldValue);

var m_fullDescriptorFieldValue = m_fullDescriptorField.GetValue(m_pmFieldValue);
```